# How can transfer Existed ERC20(WETH) into my smart contract in Matic mumbai testNet

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

I have one smart contract and want to transfer existed ERC20(WETH) into my contract. I deployed successfull my contract into mumbai testnet(Matic).

My function as below:

```
// transfer weth to smart contract
function transferWeth(address acc, address _token, uint256 _amount) public payable{
    ERC20 wethToken1 = ERC20(_token);
    wethToken1.approve(acc, _amount);
    require(wethToken1.transferFrom(acc, address(this), _amount), "Don't have enough balance");
}
```

But when run from truffle I encounted issue:

```
Uncaught Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:9
    at sigintHandlersWrap (node:vm:274:12)
    at Script.runInContext (node:vm:142:14)
    at runScript (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:248:1)
    at Console.interpret (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\console.js:263:1)
    at bound (node:domain:416:15)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (node:domain:427:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (node:repl:833:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (node:readline:364:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (node:readline:700:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (node:readline:1045:14)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (node:repl:925:9)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (node:readline:235:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at emitKeys (node:internal/readline/utils:358:14)
    at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>)
    at ReadStream.onData (node:readline:1179:36)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:379:20)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:313:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:288:9)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:227:10)
    at TTY.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
    at TTY.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:131:14) {
  receipt: {
    blockHash: '0x1ba04a25a36f6c9317099497b234b9df80a66fc16b7bfb1b50d1f1500b548291',
    blockNumber: 12518868,
    contractAddress: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 58547,
    from: '0xfcddff6d80538b0ff8ad3a914996babdcc94fe1a',
```

I also implemented function getbalance of weth from one account and this function ran successfully. My function as below:

```
// get balance of weth from account
function getBalanceOfWethA(address _address, address _account) public view returns (uint256) {
    return ERC20(_address).balanceOf(_account);
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance